# Ion slide loop shows second slide after last

Tags: ionic3

I am developing an app in Ionic 3 with slides. I am creating slides using `*ngFor` at the time of loading view. I have kept loop property to true so that slide 1 should be visible after navigating from the last slide. Below is my code

```
<ion-slides loop>
<ion-slide *ngFor="let card of myCards; let i=index">
<ion-card>{{card.name}}</ion-card>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Slides rendered correctly on the device. However, when I slide next from the last slide I see slide 2 instead of slide 1. If I slightly drag the screen when I see slide 2 I see slide 1. I am not sure if the view is not getting updated or something. Can someone please help me if I am doing something wrong?

**Edit:**
I am getting cards array from storage like this in `ionViewWillEnter` event:

```
this.storage.get(val =>{
this.myCards = val;
})
```

array has following structure:

```
[{'name': 'xyz', 'message': 'message1'},
{'name': 'pqr', 'message': 'message2'}, 
{'name': 'abc', 'message': 'message3'}]
```

Comment: Can  you try with hard coded data ? It looks like your myCards array is having a copy of second card at end of array.

Comment: Please provide myCards array data and callback functions (if any )

Comment: updated the post. I am not sure how can it has copy of second card at the end. Can you please elaborate what you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your array manipulation or storage manipulation. Try following code.

```
this.myCards = [
                   {'name': 'xyz', 'message': 'message1'},
                   {'name': 'pqr', 'message': 'message2'}, 
                   {'name': 'abc', 'message': 'message3'}
               ];
```

If above code works fine, then problem is with either your storage manipulation or array manipulation.